# How do I programmatically generate shapes similar to these?

Tags: c++, graphics, graphics2d

I am in need of help. I've been racking my brain but I just can't seem to find any good code examples of how to programmatically generate shapes similar to these (lightbursts, glimmers, sunrays, etc).

[image: http://www.richardrosenman.com/storage/lightburst.jpg]

I really need help here. Can anyone off some examples with code that might help me produce something similar?

I'm using a language similar to C++.

Answer (score 2):

These all look like a center of light bright at the center and, on moving out, both fading (growing dimmer) and diffusing (becoming more spread out).

To fade, you will want to scale the light from maximum intensity by a function of `r` (distance).  Physically this would be something like `1/r` or `1/r^2` but in your case you might have more luck using an exponential `e^(-r)` or even a linear fade `1 - a*r`

A major aspect of the effect is the diffusion.  The easiest way to emulate diffusion short of building a full on raytracer would be to apply a linear **gaussian blur** (or even a simple averageing blur) along the rotational axis.  For example, the diffused point at r = 3, theta = 0.5 might be an average of the undiffused points between r = 3, theta = 0.4 and r = 3, theta = 0.6.  You will get best effects if the "window" of the blurring function scales with `r`.  That is, the larger the `r`, the greater the averaging window, or the larger the sigma for the gaussian blur.

Finally, it looks like before the diffusion, the beam rotationally "filtered out" by a theta-varying transmission function.  That is, the amount of the beam that "escapes" the filter is a function of the angle.  This function appears to be somewhat randomized yet with apparent structure (ie, bands of light and dark, instead of simply being white noise).  This is a perfect candidate for **Perlin Noise**, which generates random data with structure.  You can customize how fine this structure is in the perlin noise algorithm; this indeed is what differentiates the three pictures you show.

So in summary:

1. First, calculate the undispersed distribution:

   - Start a fading ball of light, f(r,theta) = 1/r (or some other fading)
   - Multiply the fading ball of light by the noisy filter function p(theta) -- but maybe only to points past a given radius (to have that white ball in the middle)
2. Then, disperse everything with a radially growing blurring window
3. Perhaps add a white noise grain to everything.

I think this is just one way to generate these; there might be others, but it could be a good start.

Comment: Light intensity from a point source drops exactly like `1/r^2`. And exponential decay is _faster_ than inverse-square while linear is _slower_ - it's strange to see you suggesting "either _exponential_ or _linear_" decay.

Comment: I think the white "ball" in the middle is caused precisely because the blurring function does not decay with R. Look at the last example labelled "Glint"; the kernel in the middle has an irregular shape that  matches the dominant rays.

Comment: @PetrBudnik Light intensity physically does drop as 1/r^2; however this need not be rigidly adhered to if aesthetic quality (which is the priority) demands otherwise.

Comment: Hey guys; Thank you all for your help, especially Justin for your lengthy and detailed reply (I tried to mark it as helpful but I need more points to do so). The reason for my post is more to seek help on *HOW* to go about coding these. I do understand (and fully agree) on the theory that it starts off bright and fades off by radius. That it starts off sharp and diffuses by radius. That each ray changes angles, etc. But my problem is finding a way to code this fast - to be interactive. I've tried, for instance, emanating particles that shoot outwards and grow but the number of loops is slow.

Comment: Ideally, I'd love to have examples or snippets pasted that can show how to generate some of these shapes quickly and efficiently as they have to be interactive. So speed is of concern. In a perfect world, I would samples through all x and y pixels and plot the shape using a mix of sine and cosine curves, for example. But I just can't find example code anywhere on how to generate similar shapes / graded polygons in C++.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with defining a function f(theta,distance) that gives you the intensity of light at theta degrees of rotation and at that distance from the center. You can probably play with periodic functions like sin to change how thin the bursts are.

Another, even cooler option, would be to study some physics and figure out how such an effect happens to your eyes in the first place when you look at bright lights... Then replicate the real world math in code.